# find the count of values having zero in rows in dataframe

Tags: r

i am trying to calculate the count of zero in rows and then subtract it from 5

for eg in excel =3-COUNTIF(SM1:SM3,0)

any solution for this

```
df <- data.frame("T_1_1"= c(68,NA,0,105,NA,0,135,NA,24),
                 "T_1_2"=c(26,NA,0,73,NA,97,46,NA,0),
                 "T_1_3"=c(93,32,NA,103,NA,0,147,NA,139),
                 "S_2_1"=c(69,67,94,0,NA,136,NA,92,73),
                 "S_2_2"=c(87,67,NA,120,NA,122,0,NA,79),
                 "S_2_3"= c(150,0,NA,121,NA,78,109,NA,0),
                 "T_1_0"= c(79,0,0,NA,98,NA,15,NA,2)
                 
                 
)



df <- df %>% mutate(ltc = (5-rowSums(select(., matches('T_1[1-9]')) == 0,na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a base R option using `rowSums`

```
df$ltc = 5- rowSums(df == 0, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you forgot an underscore in `matches()`.

```
df %>%
  mutate(ltc = 5 - rowSums(select(., matches('T_1_[1-9]')) == 0, na.rm = T))
```

Comment: without underscore i am able to fetch the columns , this is still not working

Comment: What error are you getting? I'm getting the correct number for the `ltc` column on my end.